Distinguish noisy objects close to each other with cv2
I have an image that contains noisy objects and I want to distinguish them with OpenCV. Here is the image:

My code should detect the three white dots from the image. So the output should be something like this (left). However, the two noisy dots are so close to each other that the code sees them as one large object (right):


Here is my code:
import cv2
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

def process(image):
    bil = cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 20, 75, 175, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(bil, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    bw = cv2.threshold(grey, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    return bw

def main():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    final = process(image)
    cv2.imshow("Image", final)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

main()

I haven't been able to solve this problem. I came across something called CLAHE, and I tried to make a function but this does not work correctly:
def use_clahe(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5)
    apply_clahe = clahe.apply(gray)
    dots = apply_clahe + 30
    bw = cv2.threshold(dots, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    return bw

This creates an image that contains a lot of noise and the dots are labeled black. However, I want them to be white and the background should be completely black. How could I fix this?

the task is to find local maxima. do not threshold. and avoid overexposure of the objects you care about.

@ChristophRackwitz why no thresholding? The bright blobs are all 255? am I missing something?

firstly, you'll need to pick a threshold. that apparently isn't trivial, as OP demonstrated. secondly, in similar tasks, the lighting (of the background) is uneven, so a global threshold can't possibly work. thirdly, local thresholding is just a variation on finding local extrema. that's why I would go straight to finding local maxima. that too involves various parameters (minimum distance/radius, relative/absolute threshold to not react to flat black background or faint features). one could argue that those parameters are even more complicated and hard to dial in... I think otherwise.

I've posted (across SO and the opencv forum) more than one iteration of the "finding local maxima" recipe I like to apply in these cases. there are technical details and mathematical corner cases to be aware of and get right. ultimately it's very little code.

sure, in this picture, a high enough threshold works just fine. I don't know why OP didn't get to that result from just trying things, picking it manually (not Otsu), before jumping straight to CLAHE... suggesting a simple solution is rarely the end of it. people asking questions often present a trivial example first, get answers, then slap their actual specimen on the table, which invlaidates the solutions to the simple problem.

@ChristophRackwitz all good points, hopefully, OP didn't post the one picture that works with a simple threshold...

No need for complicated solutions when your problem is simple. Your image has great contrast between what you want and what you don't want.
Something like this suffices in my eyes:
im = cv2.imread("dots.jpg") # read image
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to gray
mask = imGray>240 # get mask
plt.imshow(mask) # show the mask

The results:

If you need to get the pixels from the image, the use this:
imFiltered = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask=mask.astype(np.uint8)) # filter

If you need the pixels around those detected blobs, use dilation:
mask = cv2.dilate(mask.astype(np.uint8), np.ones((3,3),dtype=np.uint8), iterations = 1)

